# How do I use octal characters in a git checkout?

Tags: git, shell, utf-8, status, git-checkout

I have a git repo of my music files, and I have recently detected that some are deleted. 
I suppose I accidentally deleted them, however now I have only too-briefly reveled in the fact that I had the foresight to
use a git repo, so my current git status verifies they have been deleted. Here is the listing of a few:

```
# deleted:  Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/03 - Arioso__J.S._Bach_.flac
# deleted: "Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/04 - S\303\203\302\251r\303\203\302\251nade__Rachmaninov__from_Moreaux_de_fantasie.flac"
# deleted: "Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/05 - After_a_Dream__Faure___Apr\303\203\302\250s_Une_R\303\203\302\252ve_.flac"
# deleted:  Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/06 - Prelude_in_C_Minor__J.S._Bach__from_The_Well-Tempered_Clavier.flac
# deleted:  Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/07 - If_Dreams_Could_Dance__Erquiaga_.flac
```

I have already restored one song that did not contain special characters in its name by using:

```
$git checkout "copy/pasted-in_name_from the output above"
```

However the special characters in some of the names are blocking my simplistic approach to restore them:

```
$git checkout 'Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/05 - After_a_Dream__Faure___Apr\303\203\302\250s_Une_R\303\203\302\252ve_.flac'
```

Error:

> pathspec 'Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/05 - After_a_Dream_*Faure*__Apr\303\203\302\250s_Une_R\303\203\302\252ve_.flac' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I suppose it is not a git issue per se, rather a shell special-character escaping or translating issue.
I tried putting the name in double quotes, as it is displayed, but I got the same message. I also tried it with outer double-quotes and preceding each 'inner double quote' with a backslash, garnering the same type of error message.

How can I construct a git checkout command that will work using these file names?

Comment: If you're happy with checking out all files and not specifically named ones, `git checkout .`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `printf`, which understands 3-character octal escapes, e.g.:

```
git checkout -- "$(printf "Steve_Erquiaga-Cafe_Paradiso/05 - After_a_Dream__Faure___Apr\303\203\302\250s_Une_R\303\203\302\252ve_.flac")"
```

I haven't tested this, I'm afraid, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes in your git checkout command.  Escape sequences generally work inside double-quoted strings but not single quoted.

And here's an even easier idea, but it could erase local changes:

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: it may be useful to explain what the command does? it's not obvious

Comment: I think `git checkout .` basically reverts all your changes in the current directory (.) to be the same as the "index" (the stuff you have added with `git add` or `git rm`).  Instead of doing `git checkout filename` to revert a file, you can do `git checkout .` to revert a whole directory.