# Bash: cat file with utf8 characters in filename

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm writing my own bash script and I have some troubles with UTF8 characters in filename.

I have file with name: `../ahh/Nový textový dokument.txt`

I get this error:

```
cat: '"../ahh/Nov\303\275 textov\303\275 dokument.txt"': No such file or directory
```

For others script works fine.

Fragment of my bash script:

```
git status -su | tr \\r \\n | while read -r line ;
do
    FILE=$(echo "$line" | awk '{$1 = ""; print substr($0,2)}')
    cat "$FILE"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `git status` or `git ls-files` you may get something like:

```
$ git status 
A  "Nov\303\275 textov\303\275 dokument.txt"
```

This is because by default `git`  print non-ASCII filenames in quoted octal notation, this can be disabled for the current repository with:

```
git config core.quotepath off
```

Then:

```
$ git status -s
A  "Nový textový dokument.txt"
```

Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828826/1135424