# Is comparing git lfs ls-files with git ls-files ':(attr:filter=lfs)' a reliable way to detect lfs files that are not managed by lfs?

Tags: git, powershell, tfs, git-lfs, git-ls-files

I try to find a way to determine whether the files in git repository are correctly managed by git-lfs.

So far, I have found that comparing results from `git lfs ls-files` and `git ls-files ':(attr:filter=lfs)'` seems to give me what I want.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Linq';
[string[]] $actualLfsFilePaths = git lfs ls-files | `
    ForEach-Object `
    {
        #'12345678 * my.dll' - not all lfs versions support -n flag, so it is better to be conservative
        $_.Split(' ', 3)[2]
    };
[string[]] $shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths = git ls-files ':(attr:filter=lfs)';
$filePathsNotUnderLfs = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray(
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except($shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths, $actualLfsFilePaths)
    );
$count = $filePathsNotUnderLfs.Count;
Write-Host "There are $($count) lfs files that are not under lfs";
foreach ($filePathNotUnderLfs in $filePathsNotUnderLfs)
{
    Write-Host "`t'$filePathNotUnderLfs'";
}
if ($count -gt 0)
{
    Write-Error "There are $count lfs files that are not under lfs";
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Still I am not sure that is a reliable way. So, is it a reliable/correct way? Or perhaps there is an alternative available?

P.S.: What I am trying to achieve is to create a pull request validation build(for TFS repository) that will detect lfs violations (files committed without being added to lfs) that often occur for one or another reason and lead to unnecessary warnings and repo bloat at best and major [nuisances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704572/git-error-encountered-7-files-that-should-have-been-pointers-but-werent) at worst.

**EDIT:** 
Well, found out that there are some issues with the current code:

1. [empty files](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2863) handling
2. [octal encoding for non-ASCII chars in ls-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827239/how-to-make-git-properly-display-utf-8-encoded-pathnames-in-the-console-window)
3. Symbolic links

but they are relatively easily fixed and do not change the gist of the question.

Comment: I get what you're after, but if this is happening during a pull request, **it's too late**. The files have already been pushed. The repo is bloated. TFS git repos don't undergo GC, so once it's there, it's there.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, but at minimum those files won't get to the the master. And then the author will fix the issue in one or another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not managed to find whether it is a truly reliable way, but so far my testing seems to confirm that.

We've ended up using the following script as a part of our build pipeline:

```
#See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804333/is-comparing-git-lfs-ls-files-with-git-ls-files-attrfilter-lfs-a-reliable
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([int])]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $RepositoryLocalPath
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

function Assert-LastExitCodeIs0
{
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {
        throw (New-Object System.InvalidOpertationException("LASTEXITCODE is $LASTEXITCODE"));
    }
}

function Get-StringFromOctal
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    [OutputType([string])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]     
        [string]
        $String
    )
    if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($String))
    {
        return $String;
    }
    if (($String[0] -ne '"') -or 
        ($String[$String.Length - 1] -ne '"'))
    {
        return $String;
    }
    if ($String.Length -lt 2)
    {
        return $String;
    }
    $String = $String.Substring(1, $String.Length -2);
    [regex] $regex = '(\\[0-9]+)+';
    $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
    return $regex.Replace(
        $String,
        {
            Param ($Capture)
            $bytes = $Capture.Groups[1].Captures | 
                ForEach-Object { [System.Convert]::ToByte($_.Value.Substring(1), 8) };
            return $encoding.GetString(@($bytes));
        });
}

function Normalize-GitLsFilesPath
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    [OutputType([string])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]     
        [string]
        $Path
    )
    # Normalize octets paths
    # Technically we could try ls-files -z, but there is no such option for lfs ls-files.
    # Or we could try to set core.quotePath to 0, but it brings a slew of problems with encodings and etc.
    # And by doing so we would change git config settings, that is not very desirable, even if we will always(?) succeed in reverting it.
    # So it is seems simpler just to parse octal paths.
    return Get-StringFromOctal -String ($Path.Trim());
}

function Is-FileEmpty
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    [OutputType([bool])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]     
        [string]
        $Path
    )
    return ((Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path).Length -eq 0);
}

function Is-NotEmptyLfsFile
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    [OutputType([bool])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]     
        [string]
        $Path
    )    
    # Empty files will be empty files whether they are under lfs or not - https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2863
    # But they seem not to get the lfs attributes, so we have no other choice but to filter them.
    return !(Is-FileEmpty -Path $Path);
}

function Get-ActualLfsFilePaths
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([string[]])]
    Param()
    Write-Host 'Getting actual lfs file paths.';
    $lfsLsFilesOutput = git lfs ls-files;
    Assert-LastExitCodeIs0;
    $actualLfsFilePaths = ($lfsLsFilesOutput | `
        ForEach-Object `
        {
            #'12345678 * my.dll' - not all lfs versions support -n flag, so it is better to be conservative
            $lsFilePath = $_.Split(' ', 3)[2];
            return Normalize-GitLsFilesPath -Path $lsFilePath;
        });
    Write-Host "There are $($actualLfsFilePaths.Count) files that are actually under lfs";
    return , $actualLfsFilePaths;
}

function Get-ShouldBeLfsFilePaths
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([string[]])]
    Param()
    Write-Host 'Getting should be under lfs file paths.';
    [string[]] $shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths = git ls-files -s ':(attr:filter=lfs)';
    Assert-LastExitCodeIs0;
    $shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths = ($shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths | `
        ForEach-Object `
        {
            #120000 1234567890abcdef 0       mylib.dylib
            , $_.Split($null, 4);
        } | `
        Where `
        {
            $symlinkBitMaskString = '120000';
            $fileChmodString = $_[0];
            return ($fileChmodString -ne $symlinkBitMaskString); # Perhaps we should check actual bitmask?
        } | `
        ForEach-Object `
        {
            Normalize-GitLsFilesPath -Path $_[3];
        });
    Write-Host "There are $($shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths.Count) files that should be under lfs (may include flukes - empty files)";
    return , $shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths;
}

function Get-LfsFilePathsNotUnderLfs
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([string[]])]
    Param()
    [string[]] $actualLfsFilePaths = Get-ActualLfsFilePaths;
    [string[]] $shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths = Get-ShouldBeLfsFilePaths;
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Linq';
    Write-Host 'Comparing actual lfs and should be under lfs files.'
    return , [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray(
        [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
            [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except($shouldBeUnderLfsFilePaths, $actualLfsFilePaths),
            [Func[String, Boolean]] ${function:Is-NotEmptyLfsFile}
            )
        );
}

function Main-WithRepositoryAsWorkingFolder
{    
    $filePathsNotUnderLfs = Get-LfsFilePathsNotUnderLfs;
    $count = $filePathsNotUnderLfs.Count;
    Write-Host "There are $($count) lfs files that are not under lfs";
    foreach ($filePathNotUnderLfs in $filePathsNotUnderLfs)
    {
        Write-Host "`t'$filePathNotUnderLfs'";
    }
    if ($count -eq 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


function Main
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $RepositoryLocalPath
    )
    Write-Host "RepositoryLocalPath = $RepositoryLocalPath";
    # It is simpler to set working dir rather than use Process.Start with WorkingDirectory everywhere, and more reliable than Start-Process (that one may in some cases have issues with return exit code).
    $originalGetLocation = (Get-Location).Path;
    Set-Location -LiteralPath $RepositoryLocalPath;
    $originalCurrentDirectory = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory();
    [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($RepositoryLocalPath);
    # Otherwise we won't get proper file paths from git lfs ls-files, as it doesn't use octal encoding
    # And using output redirection may lead us to even bigger problems|difficulties.
    $originalOutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding;
    $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
    $originalConsoleOutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding;
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
    $originalConsoleInputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding;
    [Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;

    try 
    {
        return Main-WithRepositoryAsWorkingFolder;
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "$_ $($_.ScriptStackTrace)";
        return 2;
    }
    finally
    {
        Set-Location -LiteralPath $originalGetLocation;
        [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($originalCurrentDirectory);
        $OutputEncoding = $originalOutputEncoding;
        [Console]::OutputEncoding = $originalConsoleOutputEncoding;
        [Console]::InputEncoding = $originalConsoleInputEncoding;
    }
}

exit (Main -RepositoryLocalPath $RepositoryLocalPath);
```