# Git 'ls-files' command showing a weird non-existent string as a file on Windows, how to analyze and delete it?

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows, git-ls-files

I ran `git ls-files` in my GitHub wiki repo and got the strangest file, listed actually as a string ending with ".md". The file, as far as I can tell, does not even exist.
it certainly does not show in Windows Explorer under any attribute (when grouped by attributes), even while all hidden files are supposed to be shown.

I want to understand its history (how and who created it) and to be able to pick it up with `git rm`.

what is happening ?

[image: explorer screenshot]

two trials with `git log` yielded nothing.

[image: git bash screenshot]

Comment: `git config core.quotepath off` and try ls-files again.

Comment: This worked ! thanks. But having read the "core.quotePath" documentation, I can't say that I understood what happened here :)

Comment: Changing that option tells Git to [not consider bytes over 0x80 as "unusual"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corequotePath). By default Git [prints non-ASCII filenames as quoted octal notation](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-for-Windows-Unicode-Support#disable-quoted-file-names), including your filename. See also [this commit message](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a59e5954ef19ac94522219c2f29d49a187d31d8) for some more clarification.

Answer (score -1):

See
[Zac Anger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774952/zac-anger)'s answer in the comment to my question, as well as an [almost identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828826/9899528) question from 9 years ago that I managed to miss, forwarded by [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) :

> `git config core.quotepath off` and try `ls-files` again

That did it.